# Debian 4.9.3 - downgrading gdb, which version i need?

Tags: apt, debian, gdb

I can't work with Eclipse's debug stepping due to gdb version 7.12 not supporting certain option:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
maintenance set python print-stack off
Error message from debugger back end:
Undefined maintenance set command: "python print-stack off".  Try "help maintenance set".
```

"apt-cache showpkg gdb" shows just this version 7.12 is in repository, so I can't easily revert. So question is - how do I find out which gdb version will support this command, and how do I install it?
Eclipse version is 3.8.1, so probably I should update it instead, though it's also the single version in repository.

Comment: This site is for Ubuntu only. You may ask at [unix.se].

Comment: Ok then. If this question can be closed or moved, then it'd be fine to do so. Resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Eclipse 4.7 Oxygen according to Fresh Install part of this document actually worked.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Fresh_install